# knockoutjs observableArray with data-bind checkbox

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

So I have this table of customers with checkboxes that have been bound to view model using `knockoutjs`. So the user will be able select all or some customers on the page.

What is the best way to `$.ajax` post the **selected** customers back to the server? I can only imagine iterating thru the array and copying to new array or something like that? Anymore thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ko.mapping.toJS` to get a data from the view model:

```
<button data-bind="click: onSave">Save</button>

function onSave(viewModel) {
    var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel);

    $.post({
        url: '/save/data',
        data: unmapped
    })
}
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: I only want to post the selected records though

Comment: @Rod, yeah in tha case you need to iterate through the rows and filter to the ones you want, something like `unmapped.Rows = unmapped.Rows.filter(function(row) { return row.IsChecked; })` or `var data = viewModel.Rows.filter(function(row) { return row.IsChecked(); }).map(ko.mapping.toJS)`. Either way as you noted it comes down to "iterating thru the array and copying to new array".